# Location of maximum points of a solution to $y'=x+y^2$

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In recent ODE test I faced with the following problem:

Suppose that integral curve (that is solution) of $y'=x+y^2$ has a maximum point $P= (p_x, p_y)$. Can it be located in

1. Quadrant I?
2. Quadrant II?
3. Quadrant III?

I answered the following way:

1. no
2. yes
3. yes

My reasoning: Since $y'(p_x) = 0$ then $p_x = -y^2$, so $p_x \le 0$.

However, my answer was wrong. Can you please point out my mistake and provide correct answer and solution?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: but we have $$y'(x)=x+y(x)^2$$?

Comment: Hint: you have checked the *first* derivative to check if an extremum may exist; then you should check the *second* derivative to classify any eventual extremum as maximum or minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y$ is a differentiable function and $x_0$ is a stationary point, $y'(x_0)=0$. Since we know that $y'(x_0)=x_0+y(x_0)^2$ and $y(x_0)^2\geq 0$, it follows that $x_0\leq 0$.
 Since $y''=1+2yy'=1+2y(x+y^2)$ we get that every time $x+y^2=y'$ equals zero the second derivative $y''$ equals one. In particular every stationary point is a local minimum, not a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2+x$$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=0\implies y^2=-x$, then since $y^2\geq0$, we have $-x\geq0\implies x\leq0$

Then we must consider the second derivative:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}+1=2y(y^2+x)+1$$

So for a maximum point, we know that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}<0$

We also know that $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. It then follows that $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2y\cdot 0+1=1>0\quad\text{for all $x$ and $y$}$.

Therefore none of the quadrants are valid.